# Akka Actors Java Competing Consumers

Tags: java, apache-camel, cluster-computing, akka, actor

I am trying out a competing event consumer implementation using Akka and Camel. Am using Akka 2.3.2 and Camel 5.8.0. I am connecting camel to ActiveMQ broker and using a producer to generate messages from other end. In the following code EventManager is the master which creates pool of consumers and EventProcessor is the message processing actor.

EventManager.java

```
    import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection;
    import org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent;
    import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;

    import akka.actor.ActorRef;
    import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
    import akka.actor.Props;
    import akka.actor.UntypedActor;

    import akka.camel.Camel;
    import akka.camel.CamelExtension;
    import akka.japi.Creator;
    import akka.routing.RoundRobinPool;

    public class EventManager {




        private final ActorSystem akkaSystem;

        private CamelContext camelContext = null;

        private ActorRef workRouter;

        public EventManager(ActorSystem system) {
            akkaSystem = system;

            initialize();
        }

        public void initialize() {

            Camel camel = CamelExtension.get(akkaSystem);

            camelContext = camel.context();

            ActiveMQComponent activemqComponent = ActiveMQComponent.activeMQComponent("tcp://localhost:61616");
            activemqComponent.setDeliveryPersistent(false);
            camelContext.addComponent("activemq",activemqComponent );


            int numOfWorkers = 5;

// distributing the message processing across a pool of 5 actors
            ActorRef workRouter =
                      akkaSystem.actorOf(new RoundRobinPool(numOfWorkers).props(Props.create(EventProcessor.class)), 
                        "workRouter");

        }

    }
```

EventProcessor.java

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;



import akka.actor.UntypedActor;
import akka.camel.CamelMessage;
import akka.camel.javaapi.UntypedConsumerActor;

public class EventProcessor extends UntypedConsumerActor{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(EventProcessor.class);
    public EventProcessor() {

    }

    public void onReceive(Object message) {
        if(message instanceof CamelMessage) {
            CamelMessage camelMessage = (CamelMessage) message;
            String body = camelMessage.getBodyAs(String.class, getCamelContext());
                LOGGER.info("Message handled by :" +this.getSelf().path().name());

                LOGGER.info("Message body:" + body);
        }


    }

    public boolean autoAck() {
        return true;
    }
    public String getEndpointUri() {
        return "activemq:queue:dest";
    }

}
```

The problem I am seeing is that the messages seems to be consumed by a single actor and not getting distributed across the pool. Do I need to create a separate camel route to distribute ? I would also like to distribute the processing across different physical nodes. Appreciate your inputs and best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting concurrent consumers on the AMQ endpoint

```
return "activemq:queue:dest?concurrentConsumers=50";
```

.. or enabled async consumer on the endpoint

```
return "activemq:queue:dest?asyncConsumer=true";
```

Also it seems you got the version information wrong. There is no Camel version 5.8. I assume that is the AMQ version.

Comment: Hi Claus, I meant to say activemq-camel 5.8.0 . I seem to have it  resolved . The problem was that i was running the producer and consumer codes separately . i.e loaded the queue with messages, disconnected producer and then started consumer to consume messages. But the messages are getting distributed when I run both producer and consumer simultaneously. Thanks for the suggestions!